# How to display two strings next to each other in a single-line where the right string is always fully visible and left one truncated if too long?

Tags: html, css

On my dynamically generated HTML page, I have a limited-width DIV container. Inside it, there are several rows (DIVs) which display "name" and "value" pairs (two SPANs next to each other). This is how it currently looks:

[image: My layout]

The "value" SPANs have "float:right" so that they are right aligned to the edge of the container.

I need your help with the following:

If the total width of "name" plus "value" SPANs is larger that the width of the container, I need the "value" to be always fully visible and "name" to be truncated (preferably by using ellipsis). And nothing should ever wrap to the next line.

So, for example, if the value of "occupancy_timeout" was "123456789", I need this line to be displayed as "occupancy_tim...123456789".

If this can be done easier in another way (i.e. without using two SPANs inside a single line DIV), that's perfectly acceptable too.

Comment: I think you could add `max-width: 50%` to the "name" span with ellipsis and `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I used `display: flex` in my solution I used `margin-left: auto` instead of `float: right` and I assumed the `max-width: 160px`. You can use your own value.

```css
.wrapper{
  max-width: 160px;
}
.inner{
  display: flex;
}
.right{
  margin-left: auto;
}
.left{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='inner'>
    <span class='left'>Name</span>
    <span class='right'>Value</span>  
  </div>
  <div class='inner'>
    <span class='left'>id:</span>
    <span class='right'>123456789012345678</span>  
  </div>
  <div class='inner'>
    <span class='left'>occupancy_timeout</span>
    <span class='right'>10000</span>  
  </div>
  <div class='inner'>
    <span class='left'>led_indication</span>
    <span class='right'>true</span>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @fuxoft My pleasure. Keep coding :)